# 502 Bad Gateway error when deploy the Node.Js and ReactJs to Nginx Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

I deploy Nodejs ReactJs application to nginx but get 502 bad getaway error. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: This server block is listening to which domain?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed specifying the domain name in your server block also first define the /api location and then define the / location.

Comment: I did your way but the problem is not solved.